# Parse any primitive type garnered using Reflection from a string

Tags: c#, reflection, type-conversion

I am retrieving values from text files to build several different types of objects and I'd like one central method of populating the property values for these objects. I would like for the resulting values to benefit from C#'s strong typing which means parsing the values.

The steps being

- Read the text file's key value pairs of
- Get a list of all the properties for the type I'm building using reflection.
- Set the property values to their corresponding key-value pair, converting the string based value to that of the property type.

My current implementation (which works) is:

```
 public void SetPrimitive(PropertyInfo property, T product, string value)
    {
        if (property.PropertyType == typeof(bool))
        {
            property.SetValue(product, bool.Parse(value));
        }
        else if (property.PropertyType == typeof(int))
        {
            property.SetValue(product, int.Parse(value));
        }
        else if (property.PropertyType == typeof(double))
        {
            property.SetValue(product, double.Parse(value));
        }
        else if (property.PropertyType == typeof(char))
        {
            property.SetValue(product, char.Parse(value));
        }
        else if (property.PropertyType == typeof(float))
        {
            property.SetValue(product, float.Parse(value));
        }
        else if (property.PropertyType == typeof(long))
        {
            property.SetValue(product, long.Parse(value));
        }
        else if (property.PropertyType == typeof(short))
        {
            property.SetValue(product, short.Parse(value));
        }
        else if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string))
        {
            property.SetValue(product, value);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception($"Invalid type '{property.PropertyType}'. This class will need to be extended to support this.");
        }
```

As you can see this isn't very extensible, and fairly wordy.

I've tried working with Convert or TypeConverters, as is seen in several similar questions, to parse the appropriate values and just plain typecasting but, unlike with the developers asking those questions, I am retrieving the type to convert to via reflection using 'TypeOf(T).GetProperties' and it seems unwilling to convert the value, the compiler complaining that it isn't a recognized type. This, despite it being able to confirm or deny an objects type in the various if statements above.

My theory on it is this: It doesn't know at compile time since the method is building various different types that it doesn't know about till runtime. Hence me trying to code around property.PropertyType is causing compiler confusion. However it is easily able to match any type against another and confirm/deny whether it matches.

Is there a specific way I can write this to get TypeConverter or Convert to work as expected? I'd like this to work for all primitives out of the box and let other devs add on to it if they wanted to be able to set more complex types going forward.

**TLDR; I have a working approach but its messy and it feels like there should be a better way to do this.**

Comment: I think you should read a bit into Serialization (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/serialization/) as well as the Factory pattern (https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/factory-method-design-pattern-in-c-sharp/).

Comment: I’m slowly working my way through C# Design Patterns on Udemy. Haven’t quite gotten to Factory. I’ve used it before but using it and understanding it are two different things. I’ll do some reading on it though. Thanks.

Comment: Reading through the article on serialization and some on the factory pattern I can see you're steering me towards what, under any other circumstances, might be a viable alternative, but even the factory pattern in this instance is too limited and serialization would allow me to reuse objects that were previously serialized, taking advantage of type safety, but I wouldn't be able to create new objects without first serializing them. Which would require far more than a simple text editor.

Comment: @JuanR the more I've read the more I see that the Factory Pattern would provide a viable alternative solution here. Though it would require the user to register their types with the factory etc. etc.

Would you say this is necessarily the best approach if you are only using one of these dynamic objects and there is only ever one instance of them in any given run?

Comment: You could create a factory with type loaders. You can implement them separately and look for them programmatically at runtime. That way, no user registration is necessary. This is how the stuff in app.config and web.config works and this is why I pointed you in the direction of serialization. The text file is essentially the serialized representation of the objects.

Answer (score 0):

So converting the type this way is possible by using TypeCodes. More specifically by parsing the string to a corresponding enum. TypeCodes include all of the primitives (which was my minimum requirement) while also being able to parse some common, yet non-primitive (comparatively) complex types such as DateTime.

```
        public void SetProperty(PropertyInfo property, string value)
    {
        //Get the type we need to cast to.
        Enum.TryParse(property.PropertyType.Name, true, out TypeCode enumValue); //Get the type based on typecode
        //Cast to that type
        var convertedValue = Convert.ChangeType(value, enumValue); //Convert the value to that of the typecode
        //Assign
        property.SetValue(this, convertedValue); // Set the converted value
```

It constrains me to the types listed in the enum but it works rather nicely and is far cleaner.

It might be nice to manually compare these against all these types manually and add additional logic for each but for a catch-all generified solution I think this is definitely a step up!